# Adding an existing user to another group

Tags: user-management

I am having this strange problem. I am using `usermod` to add an existing user to another group. I want to create a new user and add an old user to this new user's group. To do this, I am doing the following things

Create a new user, -m creates the home directory for the user and -U creates a group by the same name, as that of the user.

```
useradd -U -m newuser
```

Then I add the old user to the new user's group as

```
usermod -a -G newuser olduser
```

`-a` appends this group to the already existing groups and `-G` is used to give the group name.

Now when I do `groups olduser` I get the following out put `olduser newuser`, but being the `olduser` I am unable to create a any file in the `newuser` home directory. I have set the proper directory permissions, the read, write and execute bit is set for group.

However if, instead of using `usermod` I manually edit the `/etc/group` file, and add `newuser,olduser` in front of the newuser group then everything works correctly. Is there a bug in `usermod` or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing this with `adduser` instead? The [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto) page recommends not using `useradd`.  I think what your trying to do could be done like this:

`adduser newuser` 
(automatically makes home folder)

`adduser newuser olduser` (this adds newuser to the olduser *group*)

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

This should at least help you figure out if the problem is related to `usermod` or not. Try to add the user and change groups without using `useradd` *or* `usermod`.

Comment: Actually as I said in the question, the problem is not of adding a new user, that is working fine. The problem is of adding an existing user to the new user's group. I tried adding the old user to the new user created using `adduser` but the problem persists

Comment: `adduser user group` adds `user` to `group` per [`adduser(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/adduser)

Comment: Remember you need to log out and back in for new permissions to take effect.  This got me!

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that you just need to logout and login again to let the new permission to become effective.